# How to do two way data stream between parent and child components? (Angular 5)

Tags: angular

I have a simple code example where I try sending from parent component data into child component and at the same time get it data from child to parent when data will be changed:

Parent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent {

  parentData:string = 'start value'

}
<app-child [childData]="parentData"></app-child>
```

Child:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() childData: string;

}
<p>
    {{childData}}
    <br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="childData" type="text">
</p>
```

I need to annotate `@Output()` for  `childData` but it already annotated with `@Input()`.
How to binding variables `childData` and `parentData`?

Comment: You mean tow-way data binding???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in [this article](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/two_way_data_binding.html):

> To create your own component that supports two-way binding, you must
>   define an @Output property to match an @Input, but suffix it with 
>   Change.

You can see an example for your code in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aszaz7).

**Child component:**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="childData" type="text" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)">
```

```
export class AppChildComponent {
  @Input() childData: string;
  @Output() childDataChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onModelChange(value: string) {
    this.childDataChange.emit(value);
  }
}
```

**Parent component:**

```
<app-child [(childData)]="parentData"></app-child>
```

Comment: thank you. But how related `childData` and `childDataChange`in you're the example?

Comment: It appears to be a convention in Angular that when an Output property has the same name as an Input property with the addition of the Change suffix, the property can be used for two-way binding. It is also explained in [this article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html#creating-custom-two-way-data-bindings). In the child component code above, `ngModelChange` is triggered every time `ngModel` is modified, with the new value as the `$event` parameter.

Comment: Thanks. But where is this in the angular documentation.. also I don't understand why this is working. Why is ----[(childData)]="childData" --- not enough? It's two way binding right, then this should work?

Answer (score 4):

I like creating a service that both parent and child can subscribe to as well as set.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ShareDataService {

  private subjectSharedData: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  getSharedData$ = this.subjectSharedData.asObservable();

  setSharedData(data: any): void {
    this.subjectSharedData.next(data);
  }

}
```

At points where you need to pass the data you call the service method to `setSharedData(data)` the data whether child or parent. Where you want to retrieve, use `getSharedData$.subscribe(data => { console.log(data); })`.

You will need to import this service in your `app.module.ts` or which ever module. Then instantiate it in the `constructor` method of both the parent and child components.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: rxjs is incredibly powerful library, and I love it, but you don't really need to use it in this case. And if you don't mind, I will write an advice:
add .share() to your observable, so both parent and child can listen to 1 source, instead of creating 2 instances of it

Comment: @Alexandr2134 sure, go right ahead. In the case where he wants to expand communication with other components this option can scale.

Answer (score 2):

To enable two-way data binding the same way ngModel works you have to add two properties in the child component input and output with a name convention `output name == input name + Change`.
The parent component can bind then it's data to the child component and for every change made in the child component the parent will be updated

parent html:

```
    <app-child[(childData)]="parentData"></app-child>
```

ChildComponent :

```
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() childData: string;
  @Output() childDataChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

changeAction() {
this.childDataChange.emit("anything");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But where is this in the angular documentation.. also I don't understand why this is working. Why is ----[(childData)]="parentData" --- not enough? It's two way binding right, then this should work?

Answer (score 1):

you can easily use both for childData and it will work similar to ngModel.
Example:

```
@Input()
@Output()
childData: string;


<app-child [(childData)]="parentData"></app-child>
```

Answer (score 1):

The output element need not have the same name as the input. The output variable should be an emitter so that it returns the data to the bind to ngModel. Refer code snippet below:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-voter',
  template: `
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
    <button (click)="vote(true)"  [disabled]="voted">Agree</button>
    <button (click)="vote(false)" [disabled]="voted">Disagree</button>
  `
})
export class VoterComponent {
  @Input()  name: string;
  @Output() onVoted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  voted = false;

  vote(agreed: boolean) {
    this.onVoted.emit(agreed);
    this.voted = true;
  }
}
```

Refer to the following link for a complete guide:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction